# How add clips in Imperavi Redactor?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I use Imperavi Redactor 10.0.6 with plugin Clips. Ago for adding my own clips I used this solution: http://www.yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11042, but in current version this method not working. In file clips.js I found variable `items`. I can change this array, but I'm not sure, that it`s best solution.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem so:

you need to change file clips.js remove array from `item` variable, and assign this:

```
var items= this.opts.clips;
```

now you can to set options for clips like this:

```
$(function()
    {
        $('#redactor').redactor({
            plugins: ['clips'],
            clips:[['Your data...' , 'Your data is wonderful'], ['Another...','Another data is bad']]
        });
    });
```

and so on.

if you using JSON it will be like this:

```
     $settings['plugins'][]='clips';
$settings['clips'][]=array('Your data...', 'Your data is wonderful');
$settings['clips'][]=array('Another...', 'Another data is bad');
$settings= Json_encode($settings);
```

Comment: It`s good solution, but your changes will be lost after updating packages. You should make pull-request to https://github.com/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget